# Simple list merging question

Tags: list-manipulation

Another newbie question. I'm trying to figure out how to produce `rr` given `dd` and `hh`:

```
dd = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}};
hh = {x, y};
rr = {{{x, x}, {y, y}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}};

{Grid[dd, Frame -> All], Grid[{hh}, Frame -> All], Grid[rr, Frame -> All]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Join[{{#, #} & /@ hh}, dd]
```

> {{{x, x}, {y, y}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}}

Also:

```
Join[{Transpose[{hh, hh}]}, dd]
```

> {{{x, x}, {y, y}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}}